# How to display the heads, sectors/track and cylinders information of Ubuntu16.04?

Tags: 14.04

When I input `fdisk -l /dev/sda` there are no heads, sectors/track and cylinders information of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

However, In another platforms such as Ubuntu 14.04 LTS we can see the information of them.

[image: Ub16]

[image: Ub14]

Comment: It is not the actual disks geometry, but rather a translation to be compatible with the old BIOS and DOS systems - your disk DO NOT have 255 Reading and Writing heads at all - instead it have a LOT more sectors and cylinders!

Answer (score 2):

In 16.04 you need to add the `-u` parameter to display the disk geometry:

```
fdisk -l -u=cylinders
```